# Swagger 2.0 default null for List in models

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to build a model object, which contains a "string-list" key-value pair. Is there a way to default the list to null instead of an empty list?

Currently this is how the model is being setup:

```
Filter:
type: "object"
properties:
  and:
    type: "array"
    items:
      $ref: "#/FilterField"
  or:
    type: "array"
    items:
      $ref: "#/FilterField"
```

When the `or` field is empty it just generates an empty list `or: []`, is there a way to generate `or: null` instead of `or: []`?

Comment: Which language/framework are you generating? (codegen's `-l` option)

Comment: Please apply markdowns to mark inline code snippets instead of putting them between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

according to this post https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5240
it is already fixed in 2.2.2